# SQL Server Reporting Services error

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

Использую в отчете два источника данных находящихся на разных серверах и чтобы объединить данные использую функцию `lookup`. В студии отчет выполняется без проблем, но при попытке выложить в интерфейс приложения возникает ошибка:

> Выражение Value для текстовое поле "Textbox14" ссылается на поле
>   "country_cd_cons". Выражения элементов отчета могут ссылаться только
>   на поля внутри области текущего набора данных или (если выражение
>   входит в статистическую функцию) только на поля внутри области
>   заданного набора данных. (rsFieldReference)

Помогите, пожалуйста, обойти это ограничение.

Comment: При попытке через web интерфейс?